# Ajax data element is array causing Python Unexpected query string parameters

Tags: ajax, python-3.x

I have an Ajax call to a backend Python program with this calling sequence:

```
var dataArray = {

 "company_id":company_id,
 "plan_id":plan_id,
 "demographics_to_save":demographics_to_save,
 "takeup":takeup,
 "number_of_employees_with_dependents":total_deps,
 "percentMale":male_pct / 100,
 "percentEmployeesWithDependents":deps_pct / 100


   };

$.ajax({
  url: "http://ec2.xx.xx.xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/save_census_manual",
  dataType: 'json',
  async: false,
  data: dataArray,
  success: function(data) {
    company_id = data.company_id;
    plan_id = data.plan_id;



  } // success
});
```

The variable: demographics_to_save is a nested array that is structured as seen in the Chrome Dev Tools Console:

dataArray
{company_id: 84, plan_id: 61, demographics_to_save: Array(10), takeup: "0.68", number_of_employees_with_dependents: 2, …}company_id: 84demographics_to_save: Array(10)0: Array(4)0: 21: 12: 13: 1length: 4__proto__: Array(0)1: (4) [0, 0, 0, 0]0: 01: 02: 03: 0length: 4__proto__: Array(0)2: (4) [0, 0, 0, 0]3: (4) [0, 0, 0, 0]4: (4) [0, 0, 0, 0]5: (4) [0, 0, 0, 0]6: (4) [0, 0, 0, 0]7: (4) [0, 0, 0, 0]0: 01: 02: 03: 0length: 4__proto__: Array(0)8: (4) [0, 0, 0, 0]9: (4) [0, 0, 0, 0]length: 10__proto__: Array(0)number_of_employees_with_dependents: 2percentEmployeesWithDependents: 0.67percentMale: 0.67plan_id: 61takeup: "0.68"**proto**: Object

When the Ajax call is invoked, the Python responds with:
404 Not Found
Unexpected query string parameters: demographics_to_save[3][], demographics_to_save[1][], demographics_to_save[2][], demographics_to_save[7][], demographics_to_save[8][], demographics_to_save[6][], demographics_to_save[0][], demographics_to_save[9][], demographics_to_save[5][], demographics_to_save[4][]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/cherrypy/_cpdispatch.py", line 60, in **call**
    return self.callable(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
TypeError: save_census_manual() got an unexpected keyword argument 'demographics_to_save[2][]'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 631, in respond
    self._do_respond(path_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 690, in _do_respond
    response.body = self.handler()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/cherrypy/lib/encoding.py", line 221, in **call**
    self.body = self.oldhandler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/cherrypy/_cpdispatch.py", line 66, in **call**
    raise sys.exc_info()[1]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/cherrypy/_cpdispatch.py", line 64, in **call**
    test_callable_spec(self.callable, self.args, self.kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/cherrypy/_cpdispatch.py", line 197, in test_callable_spec
    raise cherrypy.HTTPError(404, message=message)
cherrypy._cperror.HTTPError: (404, 'Unexpected query string parameters: demographics_to_save[3][], demographics_to_save[1][], demographics_to_save[2][], demographics_to_save[7][], demographics_to_save[8][], demographics_to_save[6][], demographics_to_save[0][], demographics_to_save[9][], demographics_to_save[5][], demographics_to_save[4][]')

The Python code is a simple function
def save_census_manual(company_id,plan_id,demographics_to_save,takeup,number_of_employees_with_dependents,percentMale,percentEmployeesWithDependents):

## some code

return

I'd like to know why all the unexpected query string parameter errors are occurring  (see above).

I am using a Python Web Development Framework - CherryPy
When Cherrypy creates the call to the "offending" function, the call looks like this:
http://ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/save_census_manual?company_id=84&plan_id=61&demographics_to_save=%5B0%5D%5B%5D=2&demographics_to_save%5B0%5D%5B%5D=1&demographics_to_save%5B0%5D%5B%5D=1&demographics_to_save%5B0%5D%5B%5D=1&demographics_to_save%5B1%5D%5B%5D=0&demographics_to_save%5B1%5D%5B%5D=0&demographics_to_save%5B1%5D%5B%5D=0&demographics_to_save%5B1%5D%5B%5D=0&demographics_to_save%5B2%5D%5B%5D=0&demographics_to_save%5B2%5D%5B%5D=0&demographics_to_save%5B2%5D%5B%5D=0&demographics_to_save%5B2%5D%5B%5D=0&demographics_to_save%5B3%5D%5B%5D=0&demographics_to_save%5B3%5D%5B%5D=0&demographics_to_save%5B3%5D%5B%5D=0&demographics_to_save%5B3%5D%5B%5D=0&demographics_to_save%5B4%5D%5B%5D=0&demographics_to_save%5B4%5D%5B%5D=0&demographics_to_save%5B4%5D%5B%5D=0&demographics_to_save%5B4%5D%5B%5D=0&demographics_to_save%5B5%5D%5B%5D=0&demographics_to_save%5B5%5D%5B%5D=0&demographics_to_save%5B5%5D%5B%5D=0&demographics_to_save%5B5%5D%5B%5D=0&demographics_to_save%5B6%5D%5B%5D=0&demographics_to_save%5B6%5D%5B%5D=0&demographics_to_save%5B6%5D%5B%5D=0&demographics_to_save%5B6%5D%5B%5D=0&demographics_to_save%5B7%5D%5B%5D=0&demographics_to_save%5B7%5D%5B%5D=0&demographics_to_save%5B7%5D%5B%5D=0&demographics_to_save%5B7%5D%5B%5D=0&demographics_to_save%5B8%5D%5B%5D=0&demographics_to_save%5B8%5D%5B%5D=0&demographics_to_save%5B8%5D%5B%5D=0&demographics_to_save%5B8%5D%5B%5D=0&demographics_to_save%5B9%5D%5B%5D=0&demographics_to_save%5B9%5D%5B%5D=0&demographics_to_save%5B9%5D%5B%5D=0&demographics_to_save%5B9%5D%5B%5D=0&takeup=0.68&number_of_employees_with_dependents=2&percentMale=67&percentEmployeesWithDependents=67

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got around the issue by calling the function (via Ajax) with a change:
"demographics_to_save":JSON.stringify(demographics_to_save),

...then in the backend code (Python), 
demographics_to_save  = json.loads(demographics_to_save)